# Connecting a Google pixel to a host PC while using USB keyboard

Tags: usb, android, adb

Is it possible to connect a Google pixel to a PC and adb in, while having a USB keyboard connected to the pixel?

I tried the following setup, and the keyboard worked, but the PC didn't detect the pixel

- Pixel connected to USB C hub with 4 Type A ports
- USB keyboard with Type A cable connected to hub
- USB Type A to C cable connects PC to hub

I think it had to do with the fact that the type A connector is meant to connect to devices and not hosts. Hence, I can't connect the pixel to the PC when the pixel side connector is type A.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your conclusion is right.

USB is not like Ethernet or FireWire; it is strictly directional. Your first connection is from Pixel (host) to the hub (device); the second and third are from the hub (host) to the keyboard & the PC (devices).

- Even with a Type-C cable, the Pixel can either act as a host *or* as a device, but not both at the same time. If you connect it to a hub's 'upstream' port, then the Pixel is in host mode – it cannot be detected by another host as a device at the same time.
- A hub always has one 'upstream' port (acting as a device & going into a host) and the rest are 'downstream' ports (acting as host & going into devices).
- Type-A sockets *always* act as downstream (host) ports, and they can only be connected to devices. (Type-B sockets are the opposite.)
- Similarly, when you have an A-to-C cable, the type-A plug *always* goes into a host and the type-C end is wired such that it always switches its end (i.e. your PC) to 'device' mode.

See also:

- https://medium.com/@leung.benson/usb-type-c-s-configuration-channel-31e08047677d
- https://medium.com/@leung.benson/what-happens-when-you-plug-two-usb-c-host-ports-together-with-a-c-to-c-cable-4f8e912f8a3d
- https://medium.com/@leung.benson/why-are-there-no-usb-c-receptacle-to-usb-b-plug-or-usb-a-plug-adapters-f97736bb62be

Comment: So does that mean there's no way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Well, you can probably use adb over Wi-Fi instead, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Comment: I actually tried using ADB over Wi-Fi, but unfortunately, trying to connect to my device doesn't trigger the "Allow USB debugging" popup window on my device. Instead, on the host, it just fails to connect, and then shows it as offline.